# Error during compile of Megablink demo using freeRTOS for atmega2560 using WinAVR

Tags: arduino, freertos, winavr

The following RTOS .c files compile fine during 'make':

```
task.c, queue.c, tasks.c, croutines.c, list.c
```

Then I get the following error:

> serial.c: In function 'xSerialPortReInit'
>
> serial.c: 665:error: 'ulWantedBaud' undeclared (first use in this
>   function)
>
> serial.c: 665:error:  (Each undeclared identifier is reported only
>   once for each function it appears in)
>
> make: ***[serial.o]Error 1

---

I have checked that all include files identified in serial.c are available

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think it is an include file problem?  ulWantedBaud is more likely to be a function parameter, or file scope variable, that is misspelled.  The AVR demo in the official FreeRTOS download (whic is very old and probably not the best reference) contains a serial port init function with such a parameter, although not a re-init function as per your post:

xComPortHandle xSerialPortInitMinimal( uint32_t ulWantedBaud, uint8_t uxQueueLength );

(This snippet is from http://www.freertos.org/a00098.html)

Comment: Richard thanks for taking time to look over the problem.

Comment: The file serial.c is the original file with no edits but I reloaded from  source and same problem came back.  The code segment I enclosed in the problem description (line 665) is from inside the function you show in your response. the function parameter ulWantedBaud appears to be cast as uint32_t.  Would that normally be sufficient to "declare" ulWantedBaud ?